# Searching graph Facebook API using Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, twitter

I used Tweepy, the Twitter library for Python, to look at Tweets based containing specific keywords, and applying a date and location range. This process was relatively simple.

Now I would like to use python to search for Facebook posts in a similar fashion, yet facebook's data and API don't seem to allow me to 1) search for posts 2) search with multiple criteria. Is there a way to do this, or is it simply a lost cause and I should stick to using Twitter?

Comment: There is no API for Facebook to do that

Comment: So you're saying it's a lost cause? Somebody should make one. Facebook has a lot of data, and they keep track of things like "how many people talking about this topic". I bet it would be useful to a LOT of people!